# PDFBox: Retrieve radiobutton from radiobutton Group

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have created a PDF which contains a Radiobutton Group and its two Radiobutton options (Eg. RadiobuttonGroup: Colour, RadioButton: White, Radiobutton: Black). What i want to achieve is to set with PDFBox one of the two options. E.g. set "White" as selection.

With PDFBox i want now to read both the Group (Colour) as also its radiobutton children (White, Black).
When i iterate on the PDFields with my RadiobuttonGroup (Colour) is recongized as PDRadioButton and i cannot find anywhere the in the field list the two radiobuttons contained in this RadiobuttonGroup.

Is there something wrong i do in the creation of my PDF or there is another way to retrieve the radiobuttons (white/black) of a radiobuttongroup ?

Comment: try `getWidgets()` on the field. This will get the individual buttons. If you need more help, please link to your PDF, mention the PDFBox version (hopefully 2.0.7) and include your code. And explain how you created the PDF (with Adobe or with PDFBox?)

Comment: The pdf file can be fownloaded from here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=27845936121069169100&t=2784593612106916910062256 . It was generated with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC . I am using 2.0.3 from maven repository . 

In my code i am iterating though the the PDField. I get all the information i need for all the fields except of the the radiobuttons. I get only the RadiobuttonGruppe which is identified as PDRadioButton  (in the provided pdf)

Comment: I'll have a look later today... in the meantime, update your pom to use 2.0.7.

Comment: I just upgraded . Thank you.

Comment: Uhm... what exactly is your question? Do you want to set, get, or just wonder about the meaning of it all? The widgets that I mentioned in my first comment have a rectangle member.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i have edited my question. "What i want to achieve is to set with PDFBox one of the two options. E.g. set "White" as selection." Thats why i said i want to retrieve the readiobutton field, in order to "select" it also as an option.

Comment: But you didn't name them "black" and "white", you named them "Radiobutton1" and "Radiobutton2". Thus you can set them with `field.setValue("Radiobutton1");` or `field.setValue("Radiobutton2");`.

Comment: Sorry , i think there is a misunderstanding. The "White" and "Black" is just an example to describe my problem. I am aware that radiobuttons are named "Radiobutton1" and "Radiobutton2" . My question is how to select through PDFBox one of those two options. From your last comment i could understand that i had to do following. acroForm.getField("RadiobuttonGroup").setValue("White"); Or in my case for this pdf acroForm.getField("RadiobuttonGruppe).setValue("Radiobutton1"); . Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, `acroForm.getField("RadiobuttonGrupe).setValue("Radiobutton1"‌​);`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for the fast response. The new question is then , how can i programmatically retrieve all the options ? In this case, i know that there is an option "Radiobutton1" because i created the PDF. How can i identify with PDFBox  that the  "RadiobuttonGrupe" has two options "Radiobutton1" and "Radiobutton2" in order to set one of those two ?

Comment: `getOnValues()`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr that was really helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question according to [TilmanHausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) comments.

In order to programmatically select a radio option with PDFBox, we have to identify all possible options of a radiogroup. In our example **acroForm.getField("RadiobuttonGroup).getOnValues()** . This returns a Set with options "White" , "Black" . From there we can programmatically select on of those two options.

**acroForm.getField("RadiobuttonGroup).setValue("White")**