# Is there a way to access the possible options of a PDRadioButton or PDCheckBox in Pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am currently looking into pdfbox and trying to programmaticaly determine the possible values of fields while enumerating through all the PDFields in a pdf document. In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504055/pdfbox-retrieve-radiobutton-from-radiobutton-group) a user recommended a solution with **acroForm.getField("Nameoffield").getOnValues()** but the method "getOnValues()" is not defined in the class PDField, which is called by acroForm.getField(string). Is there a way to access the actual values and therefore set a (for example) random value?

My current tries revolved around trying to access said getOnValues() method, which is defined only for [PDButton](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDButton.html). I tried loading a pdf file of a government document, which has many fields with respective names and values, and tried to randomly select one of the values, yet the class and methods don't seem to allow accessing the possible values of a PDButton.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
                       
              // Creating PDF document object 
              PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
                      
              File file = new File("government_form.pdf");
              PDDocument formular = PDDocument.load(file);
              PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = formular.getDocumentCatalog();
              PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();
                      
              // get all fields in form
              List<PDField> fields = pdAcroForm.getFields();
              System.out.println(fields.size() + " top-level fields were found on the form");
                      
              for (PDField field : fields) {
                    if (!(field instanceof PDNonTerminalField)) {
                         switch (field.getClass().getName()){
                         case "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDCheckBox":
                             String fieldname = field.getPartialName();
                             Set<String> OnValues = new HashSet<String>();
                             (PDCheckBox)field.getOnValues();
                              PDCheckBox Checkbox = new PDCheckBox(pdAcroForm);
                          }
                              
                     }
                          
               }
   
               formular.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/Formular_ausgefüllt.pdf");
               formular.close();
        }
```

Comment: Please link to that government document. Not all such documents have proper forms. Btw you could change your code to `if (field instanceof PDCheckBox)`  and investigate from there. Also try opening the PDF with PDFDebugger so you see more of it. (Choose "internal structure" in the view menu)

Comment: `pdAcroForm.getFields()` only gives you top level fields, see the javadoc. Use `getFieldTree()` instead.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://www.sozialversicherung.at/cdscontent/load?contentid=10008.638102&version=1487847004) to the gov.document, and also by implementing your edits getOnValues() is not defined. Im rather looking for the reason why my debugger doesnt like the method. Also it seems like there is no connection between enumerating fields and then calling for possible options.

Comment: The fields postanweisung, Wahlkinder, Pflegekinder return [Ja] (an array). And if I do this for PDButton instead of PDCheckBox then I get even more, e.g. Geschlecht Antragsteller/in: [weiblich, männlich, inter/divers]

Comment: yes, i also had a programm, with which i was able to check that, yet programmatically in while enumerating the fields i cannot look for options. Here is my enumaration process i [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731840/21563504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new URL("https://www.sozialversicherung.at/cdscontent/load?contentid=10008.638102&version=1487847004").openStream());
    PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

    for (PDField field : pdAcroForm.getFieldTree())
    {
        if (field instanceof PDButton)
        {
            Set<String> onValues = ((PDButton) field).getOnValues();
            System.out.println(field.getFullyQualifiedName() + ": " + onValues);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Geschlecht Antragsteller/in: [weiblich, männlich, inter/divers]
postanweisung: [Ja]
geschlecht 2. Elternteil: [weiblich, männlich, inter/divers]
Famlienstand Antragsteller/in: [verheiratet/in eingetragener Partnerschaft lebend, Lebensgemeinschaft, alleinstehend]
familienstand 2. Elternteil: [verheiratet/in eingetragener Partnerschaft lebend, Lebensgemeinschaft, alleinstehend]
Weitere Wohnadressen Antragsteller: [ja, nein]
weitere Wohnadressen 2. Elternteil: [ja, nein]
kaiserschnitt: [ja, nein]
Kinder: [ehelich, unehelich]
Wahlkinder: [Ja]
Pflegekinder: [Ja]
Mehrlingsgeburt: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3, Auswahl4]
Obsorge kind: [ja, Auswahl4]
obsorge mehrlling1: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3, Auswahl4, Auswahl5]
obsorge mehrlling2: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3, Auswahl4, Auswahl5]
obsorge mehrlling3: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3, Auswahl4, Auswahl5]
Systemwahl: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3]
5a Dauer von: [ja]
5b Variante: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2, Auswahl3]
5b dauer von: [ja]
5a Dauer bis: [ja]
5b dauer bis: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2]
5c System früher gewählt bis: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2]
gemeinsamer Wohnsitz: [ja, nein]
6 weitere angaben: [ja, Auswahl2]
berufsgruppe: [Angestellte/r, Selbständige/r, Schüler/in, Arbeitslosengeldbezieher/in, Arbeiter/in, Vertragsbedienstete/r , Bauer/Bäuerin, Student/in, Hausfrau/Hausmann, Beamter/Beamtin, Notstandshilfebezieher/in, Freie/r Dienstnehmer/in]
7e ausländische leistung 2. Elternteil: [ja, nein]
einkünfte: [ja, nein]
einkünfte4: [ja, nein]
einkünfte1: [ja, nein]
einkünfte2: [ja, nein]
einkünfte3: [ja, nein]
einkünfte5: [ja, nein]
einkünfte6: [ja, nein]
einkünfte7: [ja, nein]
7a unselbständig antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7a unselbständig 2. elternteil: [ja, nein]
7a karenz antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7b landwirschaftliche tätigkeit antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7b gewerbe ruhend antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7c alv Antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7d pension antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7e ausländische leistung antragsteller: [ja, nein]
7a karenz 2. Elternteil: [ja, nein]
7b landwirschaftliche tätigkeit 2. elternteil: [ja, nein]
7b gewerbe ruhend 2. Elternteil: [ja, nein]
7c alv 2. Elternteil: [Auswahl1, Auswahl2]
7d pension 2. Elternteil: [ja, nein]
8 erinnerung: [ja, nein]
8 einverstanden: [ja, nein]
```

and I'm also able to change the fields like this:

```
pdAcroForm.getField("Geschlecht Antragsteller/in").setValue("inter/divers");
pdAcroForm.getField("geschlecht 2. Elternteil").setValue("inter/divers");
```

after saving, the fields look like this in Adobe Reader:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I also thought about trying to cast the field as a button where then the Method GetOnValues() would be defined yet i wasnt sure if that would be possible. On a second note, I think it would be very pratical, if one could access GetOnValues() without having to cast a field as a PDButton. Cheers!